# Xcode tvOS requires Running Twice to Process Changes

Tags: xcode, tvos

I have been consistently running into this since Xcode 11 and it only happens with a tvOS project. The issue is that I run the code, make some changes, and then run again but the changes aren't incorporated into the build that is run. If I then run it again, they are. This means for each change I have to run the build twice. This even includes added debugger breakpoints. This occurs on an actual Apple TV but was not an issue prior. I do not have this issue at all for any iOS projects. Why are changes only being incorporated every other run?

Comment: Can you change the build system to "legacy build system" in project /worksapce settings?

Comment: @VV - I just tried it but the results are the same.